# WebAPI not serializing inherited class on POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Here is my controller method:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/exercise")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateExercise(ExerciseDto exercise) {
```

Here are my classes:

```
public class Exercise {

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "The value cannot exceed 300 characters. ")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

}

[NotMapped]
[Serializable]
public class ExerciseDto : Exercise {
    public ExerciseDto(Exercise exercise) {
        ExerciseId = exercise.ExerciseId;
        Title = exercise.Title;
        UserHasExercise = true;
    }
    public bool UserHasExercise { get; set; }
    public List<int> SomeIds { get; set; }
}
```

If I use type `Exercise` in the API controller, the object comes through.  I created the DTO to extend the POCO with some more properties, but if I use this `ExerciseDto` class, I get `null` whenever I send the same data I was sending before.  What is happening?

WebAPI Config:

```
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        var enumConverter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter();
        json.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
```

Update:

My solution for the time being is to scrap the idea of DTOs altogether and just extend the POCO with `[NotMapped]` properties:

```
public class Exercise {

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "The value cannot exceed 300 characters. ")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool UserHasExercise { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<int> SomeIds { get; set; }

}
```

This keeps everything super simple, but I have a feeling it's not a best practice for more complicated models.  Am very interested in seeing the proper way to handle this.

Comment: Not related to your problem but I don't think it makes sense to inherit your entity object to create a DTO. Just create a DTO and copy the properties.

Comment: @Stilgar - I used to do that but it adds so much noise... ToExercise is then needed for updates, I have to track changes across two models, etc etc.  Thoughts on my update?

Comment: The purpose of a DTO is to be different from the entity it represents. It is not a kind of entity so it violates OOP practices. If you find copying tedious there are tools like automapper

Answer (score 3):

`ExerciseDto` needs a parameterless constructor in order for the Post body deserialize properly.

Update: your update is the way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you've declared `ExerciseDto` as `[Serializable]` but you're not passing all `ExerciseDto` model parameters in your request (you mentioned that you pass the same data as you did for `Exercise`). You can either remove the `[Serializable]` attribute or, alternatively, add `[JsonIgnore]` to your model's `UserHasExercise` and `SomeIds` parameters. If you're passing the data as xml and not json, then use `[IgnoreDataMember]` instead of `[JsonIgnore]`.